# how to put value in array that is also in array or to assign value to an array from another array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

This is the `array` i want to put to another array.

```
    String [][]roomType = new String[4][4];
    roomType[0][0] = "Standard";
    roomType[0][1] = "500";
    roomType[0][2] = "5";
    roomType[0][3] = "1";

    roomType[1][0] = "Double";
    roomType[1][1] = "800";
    roomType[1][2] = "4";
    roomType[1][3] = "2";

    roomType[2][0] = "Matrimonial";
    roomType[2][1] = "3500";
    roomType[2][2] = "6";
    roomType[2][3] = "3";

    roomType[3][0] = "Triple";
    roomType[3][1] = "4500";
    roomType[3][2] = "5";
    roomType[3][3] = "4";



    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
     * Costumer's Information
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    do{//Start Of First Loop - Customer's Info
    System.out.print("\nEnter Number Of Records : ");
    int Records = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    String [][] customer = new String [Records][7]; //records for customer

    for (int x = 0; x < Records; x++){ // Start For Records

    System.out.print("\nConfimation Number: ");
    customer[x][0] = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("\nFirst Name: ");
    customer[x][1] = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Last Name: ");
    customer[x][2] = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Guest: ");
    customer[x][3] = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Night: ");
    customer[x][4] = br.readLine();
    System.out.println();




        System.out.print("1. Standard..............................................P500.00\n");
        System.out.print("2. Double................................................P800.00\n");
        System.out.print("3. Matrimonial...........................................P3,500.00\n");
        System.out.print("4. Triple................................................P4,500.00 \n");

        System.out.print("\n\nPlease Select Room Type: ");
        int SwitchOne = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int two = SwitchOne;
        switch(SwitchOne){
            case 1:                 
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
```

---

Here is the process to put an array to another array or to assign value to an array from array.

```
                    for(int row=SwitchOne-1;row<4;row++){
                        int roomID = Integer.parseInt(roomType[row][3]);
                        if(two == roomID){

                            double price = Double.parseDouble(roomType[row][1]);
                            int available = Integer.parseInt(roomType[row][2]);
                            available -= 1;
                            String avail = Double.toString(available);
                            roomType[row][2] = avail;
                            customer[x][5] = roomType[row][0];

                            double guest = Double.parseDouble(customer[x][3]);
                            guest *= GuestRate;
                            double night = Double.parseDouble(customer[x][4]);
                            price *= night;
                            double totalAmount = guest + price;
                            String AmountTotal = Double.toString(totalAmount);

                            customer[x][6] = AmountTotal;

                        }
                    }
```

---

The problem is when the first array that has been put cannot be used again. the compiler says its `OutOfBounds`.

so i cannot choose what that has been chosen before.

I'm new at Java class, lend me some help.

This is 1 method class only.
i cant understand 2 or more methods.

just comment if you don't understand it, its too hard to explain.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using (multi-dimensional) arrays for this case. Create classes for Customer and Room and maybe store those objects in arrays if you have to.

Comment: It's not the array that's out of bounds, it's the index. You're using too large a number inside one of the square brackets [n].

Comment: i can't use more classes sir @HannoBinder , i don't know how and prof says only 1 method .

Comment: #Geoddie can you mention the error that your compiler is throwing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want assign two Dimensional Array from one to another one.

Follow the below code snippet,

```
String[][] newArray = new String[roomType[0].length][roomType[1].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < roomType[0].length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < roomType[1].length; j++){
                newArray[i][j] = roomType[i][j];
            }
        }
```

If you want cross-check try this one, whether the array correctly assigned, try the below one,

```
for (int i = 0; i < newArray[0].length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < newArray[1].length; j++){
                System.out.print(newArray[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Comment: I gave you the code one way of doing. if you want you can use it

Comment: Yes ! i can use it sir .

Comment: Sir @Vig Nesh ? You There ?

Comment: He's saying that he's already given you the code you need in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import java.io.*;

public class ArrayTest {
public static void main(String args[]) throws NumberFormatException,
        IOException {
    double GuestRate = 100;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[][] roomType = new String[4][4];
    roomType[0][0] = "Standard";
    roomType[0][1] = "500";
    roomType[0][2] = "5";
    roomType[0][3] = "1";

    roomType[1][0] = "Double";
    roomType[1][1] = "800";
    roomType[1][2] = "4";
    roomType[1][3] = "2";

    roomType[2][0] = "Matrimonial";
    roomType[2][1] = "3500";
    roomType[2][2] = "6";
    roomType[2][3] = "3";

    roomType[3][0] = "Triple";
    roomType[3][1] = "4500";
    roomType[3][2] = "5";
    roomType[3][3] = "4";

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------
     * Costumer's Information
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Start Of First Loop - Customer's Info
    System.out.print("\nEnter Number Of Records : ");
    int Records = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    String[][] customer = new String[Records][7]; // records for customer
    int available;

    for (int x = 0; x < Records; x++) { // Start For Records

        System.out.print("\nConfimation Number: ");
        customer[x][0] = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("\nFirst Name: ");
        customer[x][1] = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Last Name: ");
        customer[x][2] = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Guest: ");
        customer[x][3] = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Night: ");
        customer[x][4] = br.readLine();
        System.out.println();
        System.out
                .print("1. Standard..............................................P500.00\n");
        System.out
                .print("2. Double................................................P800.00\n");
        System.out
                .print("3. Matrimonial...........................................P3,500.00\n");
        System.out
                .print("4. Triple................................................P4,500.00 \n");

        System.out.print("\n\nPlease Select Room Type: ");
        int SwitchOne = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int two = SwitchOne;

        int row = SwitchOne - 1;
        int roomID = Integer.parseInt(roomType[row][3]);
        if (two == roomID) {

            double price = Double.parseDouble(roomType[row][1]);

            available = Integer.parseInt(roomType[row][2]);

            if( Integer.parseInt(roomType[row][2]) >= Integer.parseInt(customer[x][3]))
            {
                available = available-Integer.parseInt(customer[x][3]);
            String avail = Integer.toString(available);
            roomType[row][2] = avail;
            customer[x][5] = roomType[row][0];
            double night = Double.parseDouble(customer[x][4]);
            double guest = Double.parseDouble(customer[x][3]);

            guest *= GuestRate * night;

            price *= night;
            double totalAmount = guest + price;
            String AmountTotal = Double.toString(totalAmount);

            customer[x][6] = AmountTotal;
            System.out.println(customer[x][6]);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Room is not available for "+ customer[x][3]+ " Guests : We have only "+available+  " vacancy in that room");

        }

    }
}
```

}

It's working.. And the output is,

Enter Number Of Records : 3

Confimation Number: 1

First Name: f
Last Name: g
Guest: 2
Night: 2

1. Standard..............................................P500.00
2. Double................................................P800.00
3. Matrimonial...........................................P3,500.00
4. Triple................................................P4,500.00

Please Select Room Type: 1
5
1400.0

Confimation Number: 2

First Name: e
Last Name: r
Guest: 2
Night: 2

1. Standard..............................................P500.00
2. Double................................................P800.00
3. Matrimonial...........................................P3,500.00
4. Triple................................................P4,500.00

Please Select Room Type: 1
3
1400.0

Confimation Number: 3

First Name: d
Last Name: g
Guest: 2
Night: 2

1. Standard..............................................P500.00
2. Double................................................P800.00
3. Matrimonial...........................................P3,500.00
4. Triple................................................P4,500.00

Please Select Room Type: 1
1
Room is not available for 2 Guests : We have only 1 vacancy in that room

Comment: yea but if i put 2 records and i put them into the same room, the compiler says its `OutOfBound`

Comment: ok, so i register 1 so it means 1 record, it runs perfectly, but when i register 2 = 2 records and i put them in the same room, it errors.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.0"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at sample.BB.main(BB.java:250)`

Comment: I have edited that Code.. Please Try it.. Sorry for the delay... :)